# Placing a popup div without affecting other divs positions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having troubles in making an image box(width:100%) similar to the one i have uploaded.
The problem is that: I want an image box which contains diffrent images . They are displayed in "inline-block" attribute with fixed width and height.When I click on one image a div should popup(containing that image and occupying full width.)below the image without affecting the position of other images.
Please tell me how should i place the popup div below the image without affecting other images' position.

Imagebox with different images

[image]

```css
body,html{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #a6a6a6;
}
.clear{

    clear: both;
}
.searchBox{
    width:100%;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    
}
.searchBox button{
    
    border: none;
    max-width: 12%;
    min-height:40px;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
}
.search{
    float: left;
}
.settings,.edit,.dots{
    float: right;
}
.search img, .settings img, .edit img, .dots img {

    width: 100%;
     height:100%;
}
.searchBox input[type=search]{
   float: left;
   height: 30px;
   border: none;
   background-color: #e6e6e6;
   font-size: 16px;  
   max-width: 50%;
     
}
.contentBox{
    width: 100%;
    height: 80vh;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
.box{
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100px;
    max-height: 100px;
    margin: 5px;
}
.box img{

    width: 100%;
}
#popup{
    
    display:none;
    
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    
}
#popup img{

    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>MediaValet</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles3.css" >
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            var x = false;
            $('.box').on('click', function(){
             if (!x){
               $("#popup").show("slow").delay(500);
              x = true;
             }
             else {
              $("#popup").hide("slow").delay(500);
              x = false;
             }
            });
                        
            
        });
    </script>
</head>    
<body>

    <div class="medialibrary">
        
        <div class="searchBox">
    <button class="search"><img src="images/search-icon.png"></button> <input type="search" placeholder="Search.."></button><button class="dots"><img src="images/dots.png"></button><button class="settings"><img src="images/setting.png"> <button class="edit"><img src="images/edit.png"></button>
                                                                                                                  
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        
        <p>Media Library</p>
        <div class="contentBox">
                <div id="image1" class="box">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
                </div>
                <div id="image2" class="box">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
                </div>
                <div id="image3" class="box">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
                </div>
                <div id="image4" class="box">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
                </div>
                <div id="image5" class="box">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
                </div>
                <div id="image6" class="box">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
                </div>
                <div id="image7" class="box">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
                </div>
                <div id="image8" class="box">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
                </div>
                <div id="image9" class="box">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
                </div>
                <div id="image10" class="box">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
                </div>
                <div id="image11" class="box">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
                </div>
                <div id="image12" class="box">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
                </div>
                 <div id="image13" class="box" >
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
                </div>
                <div id="image14" class="box">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
                </div>
                 <div id="image15" class="box">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
                </div>  
                <div id="popup"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/"></div>
        
        </div>
        
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You would need `z-index` for popup `div`. And by the way you mean tooltip like popup.

Comment: Post your basic code and create a demo of you tried till now

Comment: @ divy3993 please check my code

Comment: @talentedandrew no images are loading, use a [image placeholder service](http://lorempixel.com)

Comment: @divy3993 now take a look

Comment: Another solution (full responsive support) is using Bootstrap Modal:

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: @YonatanAyalon you don't need bootstrap to create a modal or to make it responsive, also he wants the rows below the clicked image to shift down so that the pop fits in between the rows, not above them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By making use of each image position `top` and ``left values we position the popup which has much higher `z-index`, also on clicking any of these image we take the `src` value of that image and in inject this value into the `#popup img` `src` to load that image into the popup

**Updated**: now it is "*responsive*" and the whole set of rows below the popup shift down.

**JS**:  [**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/60qLvqaw/)

```
var imgs = $('.box img'),
        contBox = $('.contentBox'),
        popup = $('#popup');
imgs.each(function () {
    $(this).on('click', function (evt) {
        var $th = $(this),
            x = $th.position().left,
            y = $th.position().top,
            h = this.height,
            winW = $(window).width(),
            winH = $(window).height(),
            src = $th.attr('src'),
            a = 0,
            last = imgs.last(),
            shiftingDown = (winW/winH) * popup.height() - 5 * h,
            lastY = last.position().top;
            popup.detach();
            imgs.each(function (index) {
            var thY = $(this).position().top;
            if(thY > y){
                if(a == 0){
                    var nextRowFirstItem = $(this).parent();
                    popup.detach();
                    popup.children('img').attr('src',src);
                    popup.css({'display':'block'}).animate({'margin-top' : 0 });
                    popup.insertBefore(nextRowFirstItem);
                    $(this).parent().stop().animate({'margin-top' : shiftingDown});
                    a = 1;
                 }
            }else if( thY == lastY){
                popup.detach();
                popup.children('img').attr('src',src);
                popup.css({'display':'block', 'margin-top':'10px'}).animate({'margin-top' : 0 });
                contBox.append(popup); 
            }else{
                imgs.each(function (index) {
                    $(this).parent().stop().animate({'margin-top' : 0 });
                });
            }            
        });
    });
});
popup.children('#close').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    popup.hide();
    imgs.each(function () {
        $(this).parent().animate({'margin-top' : "0" });
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for this answer :) . Well I wanted  to make other divs push downward and be visible...is there any way out? if no, i will stick to this way.

Comment: I think there is a solution, just give me some time, you want the whole row to shift down or all images after that image?

Comment: :Bravo!! . awesome as ****....thank you so much for this work...I definitely owe you a beer for this :P.

Comment: I have one more question other than this question.

Comment: @talentedandrew, I prefer a large pizza :).. what's the question?

Comment: lol, yeah i think I can almost afford it :) ,
Question: can we target the last nested <ul> element inside an <li> element. using only CSS?(if we dont know how many nested <ul> elements are there inside the <li> elements)

Comment: Yes you can, by making use of the following CSS pseudo-class `li ul:last-child` http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/hxgL2vp5/ , Also same result if we use this `li ul:last-of-type` http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/uz3m00jL/ both results are *NOT* depending on the number of the children `ul`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/c1bemuwf/
i want to target the last <ul> element...please dont mind the icons...there was nothing else to placehold it :)

Comment: if the level of nesting is unknown, I think this is not doable with css only, you can post this as a question on StackOverflow and see if there's something to solve this

Comment: No one knows when css 4 is coming out, css3 is still not fully supported on different browsers, and even if css4 came out we don't know if this feature you are asking for will be there or not, i think you can do it in javascript though

Comment: yeah you are correct ...hope it releases soon with the feature i'm looking for and many more..
I did this with javascript and was successful..but i was trying to make a filetree with pure css only...now i think its not possible

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you are expecting. Cheers!

```css
body,html{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #a6a6a6;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.clear{

    clear: both;
}
.searchBox{
    width:100%;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    
}
.searchBox button{
    
    border: none;
    max-width: 12%;
    min-height:40px;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
}
.search{
    float: left;
}
.settings,.edit,.dots{
    float: right;
}
.search img, .settings img, .edit img, .dots img {

    width: 100%;
     height:100%;
}
.searchBox input[type=search]{
   float: left;
   height: 30px;
   border: none;
   background-color: #e6e6e6;
   font-size: 16px;  
   max-width: 50%;
     
}
.contentBox{
    width: 100%;
    height: 80vh;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
.box{
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100px;
    max-height: 100px;
    margin: 5px;
}
.box img{

    width: 100%;
}
#popup{    
    display:none;    
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -25%;
    text-align: center;
}
#popup img{
    width: 75%;
    height: auto;
    margin: -25% auto 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            var x = false;
            $('.box').on('click', function(){
             if (!x){
               $("#popup").show("slow").delay(500);
              x = true;
             }
             else {
              $("#popup").hide("slow").delay(500);
              x = false;
             }
            });
                        
            
        });
    </script>


    <div class="medialibrary">
        
        <div class="searchBox">
    <button class="search"><img src="images/search-icon.png"></button> <input type="search" placeholder="Search.."></button><button class="dots"><img src="images/dots.png"></button><button class="settings"><img src="images/setting.png"> <button class="edit"><img src="images/edit.png"></button>
                                                                                                                  
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        
        <p>Media Library</p>
        <div class="contentBox">
                <div id="image1" class="box">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
                </div>
                <div id="image2" class="box">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
                </div>
                <div id="image3" class="box">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
                </div>
                <div id="image4" class="box">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
                </div>
                <div id="image5" class="box">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
                </div>
                <div id="image6" class="box">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
                </div>
                <div id="image7" class="box">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
                </div>
                <div id="image8" class="box">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
                </div>
                <div id="image9" class="box">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
                </div>
                <div id="image10" class="box">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
                </div>
                <div id="image11" class="box">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
                </div>
                <div id="image12" class="box">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
                </div>
                 <div id="image13" class="box" >
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
                </div>
                <div id="image14" class="box">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
                </div>
                 <div id="image15" class="box">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
                </div>  
                
        
        </div>
        
    </div>
                     <div id="popup"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/"></div>
```

Working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/antonysuthakarj/8qbdgawL/)